# mp4 video won't play in IE9 using video.js

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, mp4, video.js

I am trying to use video.js to play an mp4 file.   It will not play in IE9.  It plays fine in Firefox and Chrome.  If I open the video in windows media player, it plays fine as well (perhaps IE9 and windows media player use the same codecs?). I have now confirmed that IE9 is not even requesting the file.

See example here: http://devonline.northcarolina.edu/lcl/ded_prod/exams/video/jstest.html

```
<html>

<link href="video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="video-js/video.js"></script>
<script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js/video-js.swf"
</script>

<body>
Video should be here:

<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" >
 <source src="http://devonline.northcarolina.edu/lcl/ded_prod/exams/video/student/invite.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The player on videojs.com page isn't even working in IE 9 or 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was that the request was going through the CMS I was using.  The CMS can't handle requests for partial files, so it just outputs the entire thing each time.  So, in my .htaccess I made it so that my mp4 files would not be routed through the CMS anymore and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try.

1. Try putting the full path to the video in the `src` attribute, e.g.
   `src="http://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/the/video.mp4"` as sometimes
   IE needs this.
2. Failing that try re-encoding the video using something like Miro
       Video Converter as not all MP4 files are the same and what one
       browser can play another may not be able to.

Comment: I added the full path, and re-encoded the video using Handbrake.  However, now I have confirmed that IE9 is not even requesting the file.  I'm not sure why.

Comment: Try removing video.js completely and use the HTML5 native video player?

Answer (score 0):

This issue also exists in IE10.

There's something going on with HTTP compression in your example. If you use Fiddler to remove the outbound `Accept-Encoding` request header, your server properly avoids using GZIP compression on the response. Then IE has no problem playing back your video.

Generally speaking, you should avoid having your server GZIP MP4 content before returning it; it's bad for performance and rarely saves a significant number of bytes (since mp4 content is already highly compressed).

Comment: Ok I will try this, although it's strange IE would indicate that it can handle a gzipped mp4 when it can't.

Comment: Our sys admin has removed compression for mp4 files.  Also, in Fiddler, I added oSession.oRequest.headers.Remove("Accept-Encoding"); to the OnBeforeRequest method, and it appears to be removing the header.  The video still doesn't show up in IE9.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "Doesn't show up"-- do you see an error message in the player ("Invalid type or file path") or is the control missing entirely? If you hit F12, what Browser/Document Mode is the page using?

Comment: Control is missing entirely. Blank, with no errors.  I tried in both IE9 and IE9 Compatibility view.

Comment: Oh, fascinating. In IE10, the video object appears but shows the error when HTTP compression is enabled. If you use the F12 Script Debugger, are there any errors? If you use "Select-element-by-click" do you see a DOM object there at all?